# How to check for emptiness of a numeric cell in Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache, int, apache-poi, cell

All is in the title.

How can I check if a `CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC` is empty with POI ?
With strings i can use the `isEmpty()` method but with `int` I have no ideas (null is not allowed and zero just wont do it).

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [it might help you](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12067629/1211000) http://stackoverflow.com/a/12067629/1211000

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Empty cells should not have format in POI since there is already a type for empty cells.

To check if the cell is empty you should test if the cell type is `Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK`. Sometimes empty cells do not exist in a `Row`; they will be `null` in this case.

Comment: This seems to be `cell.getCellType() == CellType.BLANK` now.

Answer (score -1):

You can check the raw value of the cell

```
public BigDecimal determinePorpertyValue(XSSFCell cell) {
    String rawValue = cell.getRawValue();
    return rawValue == null ? null : BigDecimal.valueOf(cell.getNumericCellValue());
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work: `cell.getNumericCellValue()` returns 0.0 on empty cells. You really need to check `cell.getCellType() == CellType.BLANK` as described in @ArtiBucco's answer above.